# Create a taxonomy view that links to different photos

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes, javascript

I'm creating a website for a business who sells and installs rail fencing for their clients.

For the fence, there are three different categories of interest:

- fence type (2 rail, 3 rail, etc)
- fence application (barrier, dog fence, horse fence, etc)
- fence material (pressure treated, pine, etc)

I'm trying to create a method of giving the site visitor to choose how they want to look at the pictures.

Each time a fence is installed and photos are taken, I want the business to be able to sign in, create a node called "Photos," Add a title, cover image, body, group of images, and then tag the node using the 3 categories above (on three separate taxonomy lines).

From there, the site would automatically arrange the added photos into the pre-configured view based on its categories.

http://fence.ckasdf.net is the site.

The menu item marked "Photos" shows a view that separates each slideshow by "job" or node called Photos.  This works as expected.

The menu item marked "View: Fence Application" is a view of taxonomy and shows the various applications.  Clicking on each link shows the various nodes (jobs) that have been tagged with that particular application, and clicking on a node shows the picture slideshow.

Instead, after a taxonomy term is clicked, I want it to load a page showing a slideshow that includes all the photos relevant to that taxonomy term.

Comment: did you try [this](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display)

Comment: Thanks for the response, arpitr. I checked it out, but don't really see what its purpose is.  I installed it, but it has no configuration in the modules screen.  Went to modify my view, and didn't see where to configure it, and the module's documentation page doesn't have much that's helpful.  Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. This module will help you overriding the existing taxonomy term path
2. You will find the module configuration under Manage Display for your vocabularies.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am adding the screenshot for the configuration section for this module which you will find in your vocabulary manage display.

Screenshot[image]

[image]

Comment: I thank you for your efforts, I have made some changes based on your information and screenshots, but now when I click on one of the things like "Dog fence," it just reloads, displays the title "Dog fence," and the links remain visible, and nothing happens.  I feel like there's something extra I'm missing.